# Ember: How to get class properties

Tags: ember.js

Given an Ember class with properties, like so:

```
User = Ember.Object.extend({
  foo: 42
});
```

how do I access the value of `foo` if I have only the `User` class? I do not want to `.create` an instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hum, try it:

```
Ember.keys(User.proto()).forEach(function(prop){console.log(Ember.get(User.proto(), prop))})
```

Comment: Hm, User.proto().forEach doesn't seem to exist, but you are right that `User.proto().foo` does the trick.

Comment: If you look closer, it's Ember.keys(...).forEach

Comment: is it the rightway to access such objects it looks like a loop around!!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved with:

```
User.proto().foo
```